# sql query to execute multiple condition without UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I am new to mysql.So basically I perform search with two condition like below

```
(SELECT * FROM `mytable1` WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('cars'  IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `domain` = 'one' ORDER BY `seed` DESC LIMIT 5)
union all 
(SELECT * FROM `mytable1` WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('cars' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `domain` = 'two' ORDER BY `seed` DESC LIMIT 5)
```

But this query is so slow and my website is crashing after high traffic.Is it possible to rewrite above query for better performance ?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you do : `(SELECT * FROM 'mytable1' WHERE MATCH('title') AGAINST ('cars'  IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND 'domain' = 'one' OR 'domain'='two' ORDER BY 'seed' DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: This will give different results - he wants 5 from domain 'one' and 5 from domain 'two', yours will give only 5 from either domain.

Comment: exactly as @MoshaPasumansky said

Comment: Try looking at why the query is slow.  Do you have indices on the title, domain and possibly seed field?  You can do this by running `explain extended mytable1` and `show index in mytable1`

Comment: @Vinbot : this is what I get http://prntscr.com/6z18hr